# What is the best practice to restrict data in the cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I tried to use DigitalOcean Spaces which is like AWS S3 to give certain users the ability to view a file like a video. I only can give them a custom link (to one file, not a hole direcotry) with a defined period of time to view .
I would like to know what is the best practice in the cloud, how to share files privately only to **registred users**.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a private S3 bucket and using the SDK, you can create pre-signed URL for a file and set the expiry time of the link.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html